# Stuck in emergency mode. Recently added partitions to a brand new drive. Ran fsck in live environment, but it didn't help

Tags: boot, partitioning, kubuntu, fstab, fsck

After I added a new drive and made some partitions, on my next boot I got:

```
[   1.920835]
[   4.999121] hid-generic 003:0D8C:005.0006: No inputs registered, leaving
[   5.947015] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: no codecs found!
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, 
"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

Super, my machine won't boot. I try pressing Control-D (as I did yesterday without issue) and I get:

```
Reloading system manager configuration
Starting default target
Failed to start default target: Transaction or graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
```

It hangs there (with a blinking cursor) so I hard reset. Same prompt, I try Control+D again. It just loops:

```
Reloading system manager configuration
Starting default target
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, 
"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

So I did some web searching which led me here, and I got the impression from posts like these:

[Stuck in emergency mode and nothing works?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960790/stuck-in-emergency-mode-and-nothing-works)

... and another I can't find that suggested I try to fix /etc/fstab and/or run fsck. Not really sure if my fstab needs fixing, but here it is:

```
LABEL=Torrents                              /home/username/Videos/Torrents   defaults   0                   0 0 
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root                  /                                ext4       errors=remount-ro   0 1 
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=00A5-98A1                              /boot/efi                        vfat       umask=0077          0 1 
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-swap_1                none                             swap       sw                  0 0 
UUID=24ef61db-8bf1-47cd-90b0-1cb9c62c62a8   /media/username/Steam            ext4       relatime            0 2
```

Running fsck in live (to get around having to unmount the partition ubuntu was running from) didn't seem to get anywhere, as it claimed I had a dirty bit, which I told it to fix, and it still won't boot.

For the record I did all of my drive mounting/partitioning via KDE Partition Manager, and did exactly zero fstab editing by hand.

Hardware:

CPU - I5 13600K
Storage - CT1000P3SSD8 (/dev/nvme0n1)
- SSDPEKNW010T8 (/dev/nvme1n1)
- WD80EAZZ-00BKLB0 (/dev/sda)

Software:

Kubuntu LTS 22.04.?

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted... Did I not provide enough information? Is it a stupid question?

Answer (score 0):

So I commented out the first line of my fstab, such that it now looks like this:

```
#LABEL=Torrents                              /home/username/Videos/Torrents   defaults   0                   0 0
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root                  /                                ext4       errors=remount-ro   0 1 
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=00A5-98A1                              /boot/efi                        vfat       umask=0077          0 1 
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-swap_1                none                             swap       sw                  0 0 
UUID=24ef61db-8bf1-47cd-90b0-1cb9c62c62a8   /media/username/Steam            ext4       relatime            0 2
```

And now it boots (with some error messages thrown too fast for me to read). Still don't know what went wrong other than KDE Partition Manager must have added that first line when it shouldn't have?